# Why do I not receive the WM_MENUCHAR message?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, explorer, windows-shell

I implemented an `IContextMenu3` interface and I am trying to capture keystrokes for my own custom accelerator. The problem is that if i hover over my submenu in the root menu I dont get any `WM_MENUCHAR` messages whereas if I hover over a submenu that is inside one of my submenu's then I do.

I know that the `WM_INITMENUPOPUP` message only gets sent if there is a child. The `WM_MENUCHAR`has the caveat that no accelerators are bound to the key. I know this caveat to be held since when I press a key, I get the distinctive 'no-accelerator' beep.

Is there another caveat that I am not aware of?

This is the smallest code I can get that reproduces the problem:

```
HRESULT CFolderViewImplContextMenu::QueryContextMenu(HMENU hmenu, UINT uMenuIndex, UINT idCmdFirst, UINT idCmdLast, UINT /* uFlags */)
{
UINT uID = idCmdFirst;
HMENU hSubmenu = CreatePopupMenu();

MENUITEMINFO mii = { 0 };
mii.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
mii.fMask = MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_ID | MIIM_STRING;
mii.dwTypeData = str_toWchar("test");
mii.wID = uID++;
mii.hSubMenu = hSubmenu;    

InsertMenuItem ( hmenu, 0, TRUE, &mii );
InsertMenu ( hSubmenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION, uID++, L"&Notepad" );
InsertMenu ( hSubmenu, 1, MF_BYPOSITION , uID++, L"&Internet Explorer" );

HMENU hSubmenu2 = CreatePopupMenu();
MENUITEMINFO mii2 = {0};
mii2.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);

mii2.fMask  = MIIM_ID | MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_SUBMENU;
mii2.fType  = MFT_OWNERDRAW;
mii2.wID    = uID++;
mii2.hSubMenu = hSubmenu2;
InsertMenuItem ( hSubmenu, 0, TRUE, &mii2 );

InsertMenuA ( hSubmenu2, 0, MF_BYPOSITION, uID++, "");

return MAKE_HRESULT ( SEVERITY_SUCCESS, FACILITY_NULL, uID - idCmdFirst );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the first item in the submenu. If the first item in the submenu is also a submenu, then the message doesnt get passed. So I instead put a normal item there.

Comment: That makes sense, because `GetMenuItemID` fails on submenus. Therefore the attempt to guess which context menu extension gets the `WM_MENUCHAR` command fails. I missed that you snuck a submenu into position 0 at the last second.

Answer (score 4):

`WM_MENUCHAR` is forwarded only for submenus. (It can't be forwarded for top-level menu items because that would be a Catch-22. You want to forward it to the context menu handler for the menu item that the the key corresponds to, but you can't do that until you have the answer to `WM_MENUCHAR`!)

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I want the message forwarded to the context of the submenu in which the mouse is hovering over. Or, are you saying that a top-level submenu is different from a non top-level submenu?

Comment: If a submenu is open, then the shell can figure out which shell extension to send the message to because all the IDs on that submenu belong to your extension, so the choice is obvious. But if no submenu is open, then it is not obvious which shell extension should get the message.

Comment: yes, that makes sense. But the case that i'm describing (a submenu open with all of the ids belonging to my extension) my extension still isnt getting the message!

Comment: My guess is that you didn't assign the IDs properly. You didn't post any code so that's all I can say.

Comment: added sample code to insert a submenu, is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: That code does not demonstrate how `uID` is related to the parameters to `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu` or its return value.

Comment: I have updated the code to show the smallest amount of code I can get that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:
If you are handling IContextMenu3 messages, consequently WM_DRAWITEM, you can use WindowFromDC() to get menu window's HWND from WM_DRAWITEM, then subclass it and catch WM_KEYDOWN or do whatever you like with it.
I tried it (was doing some other stuff than this) and it works.